# Basic Calculator isn't working with my functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I've coded a simple calculator in Python 3.7, but it doesn't work with my functions. The variable "output" is grayed out, but I don't know why.

---

```
n1 = 0
n2 = 0
op = 0
res = 0
output = 0

# DEFINING FUNCTIONS

def askAndStore(aasText,var2save):
    print(aasText)
    var2save = input()

def calculate(num1,num2,op,output):
    if op == "add":
        output = float(num1) + float(num2)
    elif op == "sub":
        output = float(num1) - float(num2)
    elif op == "mul":
        output = float(num1) * float(num2)
    elif op == "div":
        output = float(num1) / float(num2)
    else:
        print("Error: Unknown operation")


# PROGRAM MAIN

askAndStore("What is the first number?", n1)
askAndStore("What is the second number?", n2)
askAndStore("What is the operation?", op)
calculate(n1, n2, op, res)
print(res)
```

---

My output is:

---

```
What is the first number?
10
What is the second number?
5
What is the operation?
add
Error: Unknown operation
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

It always shows "Error: Unknown operation", eventhough I entered "add" as operation.
Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: There's a lot of fundamental issues here. Don't feel bad, it is a common stumbling block. But you need to learn about what it means to `return` a value from a function. Currently, you create a bunch of local variables in `askAndStore`, which are immediately discarded when that function terminates, and your call to `calculate(n1, n2, op, res)` is using the global values you initialize at the top of your script. This same issue exists in your `calculate` function itself...

Comment: I highly recommend your read the following post, written by StackOverflow legend: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1):

```
n1 = float(input("What is the first number? "))
n2 = float(input("What is the second number? "))
op = str(input("What is the operation? "))

# DEFINING FUNCTIONS


def calculate(num1, num2, opr):
    if opr == "add":
        output = num1 + num2
    elif opr == "sub":
        output = num1 - num2
    elif opr == "mul":
        output = num1 * num2
    elif opr == "div":
        output = num1 / num2
    else:
        print("Error: Unknown operation")
    return output

print(calculate(n1, n2, op))
```

Comment: Oh yeah just realised that i could of had just one at the end. Thanks for telling me an improvement

Comment: A mistake I made in my answer was to not exit the `calculate` function before returning `output` in case of an unknown operation. (I ended up raising an exception.)

Answer (score 0):

`var2save` is local to the `askAndStore` function. To access it from outside the function, you must `return` it. With minor modifications:

```py
def calculate(num1,num2,op):
    if op == "add":
        output = float(num1) + float(num2)
    elif op == "sub":
        output = float(num1) - float(num2)
    elif op == "mul":
        output = float(num1) * float(num2)
    elif op == "div":
        output = float(num1) / float(num2)
    else:
        raise ValueError("Unknown operation " + op) 
    return output

n1 = input("What is the first number?")
n2 = input("What is the second number?")
op = input("What is the operation?")
output = calculate(n1, n2, op)
print(output)
```

Comment: While this attempts to keep the OP's idea of the askAndStore function, it's not necessary because python's builtin input function can take a string as an argument to print as the prompt. So the prompt() function here is doing something that builtin input() already knows how to do.

Comment: @AlyT this is true, although the OP's confusing is more fundamental

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree, I just figured a couple people had already addressed the concerns over not including return statements and wanted to provide some extra insight on how to use the input function.

Answer (score -1):

Im guessing you was a `C` program? or something like this, in python you can not reassign values that past to a function like this, when you passing argument into function, its just the pointer to this `PyObject`, and you can not change this pointer address, only it's values (reassign the variable will never work for this)

as you can see you can use the `return` statement for those cases

```py
def calculate(num1,num2,op):
    output = None
    if op == "add":
        output = float(num1) + float(num2)
    elif op == "sub":
        output = float(num1) - float(num2)
    elif op == "mul":
        output = float(num1) * float(num2)
    elif op == "div":
        output = float(num1) / float(num2)
    else:
        print("Error: Unknown operation")
    return output

# PROGRAM MAIN

n1 = input("What is the first number?")
n2 = input("What is the second number?")
op = input("What is the operation?")
res = calculate(n1, n2, op)
print(res)
```

Take a look that complicated object does work as this, like `list`

```py
def f(l):
    l.append(1)
l = []
f(l)
print(l) # [1]
```

but you can not reassign pointer as this:

```py
def f(l):
    l = [1]
l = []
f(l)
print(l) # []
```

Comment: Python doesnt' have "primitives" and uses the same evaluation strategy for all objects. If you had done `x = []`  inside a function it will similarly not have an effect outside the function, exactly the same as an `int` object. Python *doesn't have pointers either*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, i had hard time to explain what i mean, and pretty much everything is pointer in python... its all PyObjects in the back

Comment: It doesn't matter, *python the language* doesn't have pointers. That there is some PyObject pointer in CPython is an implementation detail, you can implement Python using Java which also doesn't have pointers. Anyway, the issue here is the OP doesn't understand local versus global variables. You can modify a global (or a nonlocal) variable inside a function, although (especially for global variables) that is a bad practice, and you should instead use `return`. Truely I think this is just more confusing to a beginner than it is helpful. I understand what you are trying to say, though.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It does effect the answer, The working with varibales in python works the same as working with pointers in this type of problems, If you think about it as you think of pointer, this problem is easly explained and teachable

Comment: No, it is not like working with pointers. You could maybe say it's like working with poiinters that automatically get dereferenced and that you can never actually treat as pointers... but [it is better to understand Python on it's own terms](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) instead of shoe-horning in concepts from languages that are very different and *again* I must repeat **python doesn't have pointers** so it is simply misleading and ultimately confusing. It is much simpler to explain the straighforward concept of local versus global variables, which is the actual issue here.

Comment: I agree with @juanpa.arrivillaga, doubly so since OP is clearly a beginner and doesn't need things to be further complicated.